# Manually tweak IndexedDB document

Tags: google-chrome-app, indexeddb

I am writing a Chrome Packaged App that uses the IndexedDB for data storage. Chrome allows me to view the contents of the database, but I can't find any way to manually change the data. I need to update this data from time to time because, you know, I'm still writing the app. Any idea how to manually change the data in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any changes to the IndexedDB database have to be performed via the IndexedDB API. There are no utilities, data editors, query apps, loaders, importers, or any other kind of external utility, such as there is for MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, or any other such database.

Furthermore, it's not even theoretically possible to write such a utility, because an IndexedDB database is sandboxed inside a single app, and no other app can access it.

What I do is incorporate the needed update forms and commands (delete database, create database, count rows, etc.) as modules inside the app, perhaps accessible from a Maintenance or Admin menu item. Obviously, this is a lot of work, but there is no other way if you're using IndexedDB.

In addition, I have a "load database" menu item that loads it from JSON in an external file. I do that from time to time when I want the app to have some initial data, or test data. But, this is just an example of what I said in the first sentence, above.

Comment: "Furthermore, it's not even theoretically possible to write such a utility, because an IndexedDB database is sandboxed inside a single app, and no other app can access it." Well the browser makers could do it, since browsers like Chrome already provide viewers. And couldn't some Greasemonkey script or browser plugin work?

Comment: The browser is not a Chrome App and isn't constrained by sandboxing. Plugins are.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5 Storage Manager All in One](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-storage-manager-all/giompennnhheakjcnobejbnjgbbkmdnd?hl=en) folks promise they'll have indexedDB support soon.

They use some tricks to open extension window inside the same domain as debugged page, thus making indexedDb accessible.

Doesn't work successfully at the time of this writing, though.